# Count number of rows for each id to create a new column

Tags: sql-server

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 10 |

I want to add another column called count, that has for each id the number of observations.

Transformed table

| id | value | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `OVER()` clause to aggregate.

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  value, 
  [count] = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
FROM dbo.TableName;
```